# How can I display past 3 months?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Current Date : 2019-10-14

I try like this :

```
var b = new Date()
var c = new Date(b.setMonth(b.getMonth() + 3));
c = c.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
console.log(c)
```

The result :  2020-01-14

But I want maximum date is last date on the third month. That is 2019-12-31

How can I do it?

**Update**

For example :

Current Date : 2019-11-03, then the result is 2020-01-31

Current Date : 2020-01-09, then the result is 2020-03-31

Comment: set the Date to 1, add four months, subtract one day

Comment: Don't you want a check if it the years don't match up return 2019-12-31?

Comment: Dear first can you clear about past or future? Because in title you wrote past 3 months and in description you wrote for future 3 months last date?

Comment: @MadhuriPatel I mean display the last 3 months or 3 months to come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass 1 as third argument in `date` constructor:

```js
var b = new Date()
b.setMonth(b.getMonth() + 3);
var c = new Date(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), 1);
c = c.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
console.log(c)
```

Comment: The result is 2019-12-30. Should 2019-12-31

Comment: @SuccessMan corrected (modified as per your need), could you check now ?

Comment: `b.setMonth(b.getMonth() + 3)` may add more months than you think. 30 November + 3 months will be 1 or 2 March. Also, *toISOString* may have a different date due to the timezone offset.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var b = new Date();
var c = new Date(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth() + 3, 0);
console.log(c)
console.log(c.toISOString().substr(0, 10))
console.log(c.toLocaleDateString())
```

```
var b = new Date();
var c = new Date(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth() + 3, 0);
console.log(c);
c = c.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
console.log(c);
```

```
Tue Dec 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
2019-12-31
```

Bilals "first" answer is actually correct. Its because toISOString and your time zone offset which you can fix with getTimezoneOffset() or use toLocaleDateString() method.

Comment: Be careful with *toISOString*. For users east of Greenwich, the above will show 1 day earlier than you expect. Run on 15 Oct 2019, a user in GMT+10 will get "2019-12-30T14:00:00.000Z", 2019-12-30, 31/12/2019.

Comment: Bilals answer is not a good one and will fail regularly. It doesn't add the months correctly, it doesn't set the date to the end of the month and the use of *toISOString* can offset the date by one day for some users.